# Multi-user video-conferencing with Lync SDK in UI suppression mode: video window is lost

Tags: video, skype-for-business, lync-client-sdk

I checked samples provided in
https://github.com/tomorgan/Lync-UISuppression-VideoAutoAnswer.git
and
https://github.com/shanselman/LyncAutoAnswer.git

They are generally working with Lync SDK 2013 and Skype for Business client 2015+, but only in "user-to-user" case.
I call SDK-enabled app from non-UI suppressed SfB. When 3rd person is added to call, video window is lost.

How should I support multi-user conferencing?

Comment: I tried conference with 3 persons basing on LyncSDK\samples\AudioVideoConversation. I tried to use 3rd render/capture video window pair setting them up for AVModality of 3rd participant in conversation_ParticipantAdded. But I only see 3rd participant video once on main Incoming panel video, shortly and for unknown reason.

Comment: Then I tried own minimalistic form with minimum of SDK events and calls. It still looks like maximum 2 video streams are available: yours local and conference initiator.